# Getting user's manager in SharePoint (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-addin, user-accounts

I'm having trouble with getting user's manager data in SharePoint Javascript Model.

I'm using  `context.get_web().get_siteUserInfoList();` through `SiteUserInfoList`. What I got back is a bunch of info about a user (Title, JobTitle, Department, Office etc...) except who's that user manager.

What I'm missing? Or how can i get user's manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://sympmarc.com/2010/10/29/capturing-the-current-users-manager-in-moss-using-spservices-and-getuserprofilebyname/) blogpost describes how to get the current users manager by using the SPservices library.

The SPServices libary can be found on [codeplex](http://spservices.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Note, this would require having SharePoint Server with a User Profile Service Application.

Comment: Thanks, I gave it a shot but ultimately got it working through `SP.UserProfiles.UserProfilePropertiesForUser`

Answer (score 3):

Hi i know this is an old question, but here's a result that doesn't use SPServices:

Note that this answer is inspired from [this post](http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/07/sharepoint-2013-get-userprofile.html#gist6042056)

The method to get the manager of a user by user_email:

```
function getManagerOfUser(user_email, onComplete) {
    SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
    // Create the client context and get the PeopleManager instance.
    var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext);

    // Get user profile properties for the target user.
    // Specify the properties to retrieve and create the UserProfilePropertiesForUser object.
    // Then get the requested properties by using the getUserProfilePropertiesFor method.
    var profilePropertyNames = ["Manager"];

    var userProfilePropertiesForUser = new SP.UserProfiles.UserProfilePropertiesForUser(clientContext,
        "i:0#.f|membership|" + user_email,
        profilePropertyNames);

    var userProfileProps = peopleManager.getUserProfilePropertiesFor(userProfilePropertiesForUser);

    clientContext.load(userProfilePropertiesForUser);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
        if (userProfileProps[0]) {
            var user = clientContext.get_web().ensureUser(userProfileProps[0]);
            clientContext.load(user);
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
                onComplete(user);
            }, function (sender, args) {
                console.log(args);
            });
        } else {
            onComplete(null);
        }
    }, function (sender, args) {
        console.log(args);
    });
   }, 'SP.UserProfiles.js');
}
```

To use the code:

```
getManagerOfUser("me@mydomain.com", function (result) {
  console.log(result.get_title());
});
```

Note that the result is of type SP.User

Answer (score 0):

You can use REST API to get it easily:

```
_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties"
```

For more information, read [Get Current Logged in User & Manager using REST API in SharePoint](http://sharepoint-works.blogspot.com/2016/10/get-current-logged-in-user-manager.html)